# Tornado Damage Modeling

Tags: probability

Thank you in advance everyone. I know how to do the problem, but once again, I'm wondering why my way doesn't work.

Here is the problem:

> A company is reviewing tornado damage claims under a farm insurance
>   policy. Let $X$ be the portion of a claim representing damage to the
>   house and let $Y$ be the portion of the same claim representing damage
>   to the rest of the property. The joint density function of $X$ and $Y$ is
>
> $$f(x,y) = 6[1-(x+y)]\text{, }\quad  x > 0,\text{ } y > 0,\text{ } x + y < 1\text{.}$$
>
> Determine the probability that the portion of a claim representing
>   damage to the house is less than $0.2$.

What I did was establish $f_x(X) = 3-6x$ since $X$ represents *damage to the house.* Then I integrated the function from $0$ to $0.2$ and I got an answer of $0.48$, however, the actual answer is $0.488$.

I know how they got the answer, I just don't understand why my way was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do it like you did, first finding the density of $X$. To do this, we "integrate out" $y$. So we want
$$\int_0^{1-x}6(1-x-y)\,dy.$$
The integration goes from $y=0$ to $y=1-x$ because of the condition $x+y\lt 1$. The integral is 
$$\left. 6\left(y-xy-\frac{y^2}{2}\right)\right|_0^{1-x}.$$
Plug in. We get $6\left(1-x-x(1-x)-\frac{1}{2}(1-x)^2\right)$.
This simplifies to $3(1-x)^2$.

Now integrate from $x=0$ to $x=0.2$. Equivalently, find the double integral of the joint density, $y=0$ to $1-x$, $x=0$ to $x=0.2$.

Comment: Solved! Thank you, I realize that I messed up my area of integration.

Comment: I had an integration error. Please see corrected answer.